# How to persist an attribute of type YearMonth from joda time into one column?

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

I would like to persist the joda-time type YearMonth but I couldn't find any persistent type available (see [here](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/hibernate/userguide.html)) for storing it into one column ?

Is there any Hibernate type that I can use straightforward for this purpose ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I could not find any solution on the web, we have implemented our own custom hibernate type, using an Integer type representing a YearMonth in the DB

Here are the steps :

1- Create the persistent class `PersistentYearMonth`

```
public class PersistentYearMonth extends AbstractSingleColumnUserType<YearMonth, Integer, IntegerColumnYearMonthMapper> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4204097887942539571L;
}
```

2- Create the mapper `IntegerColumnYearMonthMapper`

```
public class IntegerColumnYearMonthMapper extends AbstractIntegerColumnMapper<YearMonth> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9060971007814071116L;

    @Override
    public YearMonth fromNonNullString(String s) {
        return YearMonth.parse(s, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMM"));        
    }

    @Override
    public YearMonth fromNonNullValue(Integer value) {
        return fromNonNullString(value.toString());        
    }

    @Override
    public String toNonNullString(YearMonth value) {

        return value.toString( DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMM"));
    }

    @Override
    public Integer toNonNullValue(YearMonth value) {
        return Integer.valueOf(toNonNullString(value));
    }
}
```

3- If you use XML hibernate mapping, register the custom type into the `hbm.xml` file when needed

```
    <property name="monthOfYear" type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentYearMonth" />
```

or if you are with annotations, register it as this:

```
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentYearMonth")
```

Comment: Nice!
Though it should be possible to create a more generic converter for storing Partial's as ISO-8601 Strings. But even joda's ISODateTimeFormat is not generic enough.

Comment: What do you do with the mapper in Step 2?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, Step 2 goes into Step 1. I didn't see the part that was cut off on the right. Had to scroll to the right to see the mapper being used.